# Como instalar ipa de mi aplicación expo en mi ipad?

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

Tengo mi aplicación ios hecha con expo, logre compilarla y me dejo un archivo ipa, al intentar instalarlo en mi ipad con me sale el siguiente problema

[image: Aplicación despues de intalarla]

No se si para probarla tengo que subirla directamente al App Store?

Estoy utilizando la versión de expo: 48.0.21